# Open application from Page tab in full width

Tags: facebook, tabs, facebook-canvas

I have created a Page for my Facebook canvas application and there added a new tab that displays the login page for the application. However, when a user clicks the login button, I would like to open the application (http://apps.facebook.com/amiinteresting) in "full screen", not inside IFrame of the page. The reason is that my application requires more width than can fit within a page tab.

Is this possible to accomplish with JavaScript or in some other way?

Here are a couple of images to describe the problem and the desired behavior:

**Application displayed on page tab (current behavior - not what I want):**

[image: Application displayed on page tab (current behavior - not what I want):**]

**Application displayed in a new window (this is what I want):**

[image: Application displayed in a new window (this is what I want)]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: is this login button clicked by the user? or is it automatically redirected?

Comment: The login button should be clicked by the user. It doesn't necessarily need to be a button that triggers authentication, it could just be a "Go to application" button also. But I want it right on the page as the regular "Go to app" button is so small and almost hidden in the top right.

Comment: did you check my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific requirement, assuming you have an `<a>` tag as the button, just specify the property `target = '_top'` ,  which will open the link in the top level, i.e change the browser address, so your link will be :

```
<a href="http://apps.facebook.com/amiinteresting" target="_top">Go to application</a>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I didn't think that would work from within an IFrame, but it appears to do so! So, thank you!